# how to get multiple cell values in a single cell in sqlserver

Tags: sql-server

i want to get all the employee names in one cell in sqlserver. values should come with comma separated in one cell.

```
output
arvind
chang
deepak
```

desired output

```
Arvind, Chang, Deepak
```

query

select EmpName from Employee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 SELECT STUFF((SELECT ', ' + upper(left(EmpName,1)) + substring(EmpName,2,len(EmpName))
            FROM Employee
            FOR XML PATH('')) ,1,1,'') AS EmpName
```

I hope it will work for you.

Comment: thanks its working but i need first letter of all names should be Capital.

Comment: I've edited with first letter is UPPER

Comment: there is space coming between name and comma.which shouldn't come, after comma there should be some space but not before the comma.

Comment: You can remove space in **SELECT ', '**. There will be not space coming between name and comma.